# how to add a subview to a view controller?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a green rectangle, but it won't display when i run the app.
here is my code:

```
- (void) makeBlockg {

    x = arc4random()%(320) + 1;

    CGRect block = CGRectMake(x, 0, 100, 70);

    greenblock.frame = block;

    greenblock.self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    [self.view addSubview:greenblock];

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `greenblock.backgroundColor`?

Comment: Try `greenblock = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame: block]`, and what Nathan said

Comment: where do you allocate greenblock??

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me. Are you sure you are correctly initialising greenblock with `greenblock = [[UIView alloc] init]`? Without doing this greenblock is nil, instead of being an empty UIView object.

Comment: thank you so much! I've been working on this for a while now... I guess I just forgot to allocate it.